# What is this prefix in TCP data?

Tags: xml, networking, tcp, protocols, reverse-engineering

I'm currently trying to write a module that can send and receive messages to an existing system via TCP. Unfortunately, there is no documentation. The messages themselves are XML, but each message seems to be prefixed by 8 bytes. This is a typical message as seen in Wireshark:

[image]

As you can see, the data part of the TCP packet starts with 8 bytes, then the XML message follows. I noticed that the first 4 bytes of the prefix are always the same, only the last four bytes change:

`04 00 00 11 [?] [?] [?] [?]`

Does anybody have a clue what that could be? I did not recognize any patterns.

Comment: The first four bytes could be some kind of message indicator? The second 32-bit word could either be a checksum or a length? For the packet you show `0x00000321` is decimal `801` which seems to fit with it being the length of the message data (809 - 8 = 801).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually did not think about endianess! Your assumption is totally plausible, but something still goes wrong... but I feel I'm on the right track now.

Comment: If there is no documentation you shoulld reject the assignment.

Comment: I would also expect the second 4 bytes to be a  message length indicator in little endian format. The first 4 bytes are maybe some message type or  simply a magic field for detecting message boundaries.

Comment: Are you sure that this is TCP? UDP uses an eight octet header.

Comment: RE the module responsible for creating the messages. Also, check out [RE.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: SYS_V: Thanks, didn't notice this subsite yet.